# Parsing commas and quotemarks in degenerate CSV files with Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse strings inputs where the columns are separated by columns and any field that contains a comma in the data is wrapped in quotes (commas separated, quoted text identifiers).  For this project I need to remove the quotes and any commas that occur between pairs of quotes.  Basically, I need to remove commas and quotes that are contained in fields while preserving the commas that are used to separate the fields.  Here's a little code I put together that handles the simple scenario:

```
// Sample input 1: This works and covers 99% of the records that I need to parse.
string str1 = "an_email_address@somewhere.com,2010/03/27 12:2:02,,some_first_name,some_last_name,,\"This Address Works, Suite 200\",Some City,TN,09876-5432,9795551212x123,XYZ";
str1 = Regex.Replace(str1, "\"([^\"^,]*),([^\"^,]*)\"", "$1$2");
Console.WriteLine(str1);
// Outputs: an_email_address@somewhere.com,2010/03/27 12:2:02,,some_first_name,some_last_name,,This Address Works Suite 200,Some City,TN,09876-5432,9795551212x123,XYZ
```

Although this code works for most of my records, it doesn't work when a field contains more than one comma.  What I would like to do is modify the code so that it remove each instance of a comma contained within the column no matter how many commas there are in the field.  I don't want to hard code only handling 2 commas, or 3 commas, or 25 commas.  The code should just remove all the commas in the field.  Below is an example of what my code doesn't handle properly.

```
// Sample input 2: This doesn't work since there is more than 1 comma between the quotes.
string str2 = "an_email_address@somewhere.com,2010/03/27 12:2:02,,some_first_name,some_last_name,,\"i,l,k,e, c,o,m,m,a,s, i,n ,m,y, f,i,e,l,d\",Some City,TN,09876-5432,9795551212x123,XYZ";
str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "\"([^\"^,]*),([^\"^,]*)\"", "$1$2");
Console.WriteLine(str2);
// Desired output: an_email_address@somewhere.com,2010/03/27 12:2:02,,some_first_name,some_last_name,,i like commas in my field,Some City,TN,09876-5432,9795551212x123,XYZ
```

How can I accomplish this with regular expressions?

Comment: The format you're describing matches CSV exactly. Why not use an existing CSV parser?

Comment: I'm using SSIS to import a few thousand legacy log files.  However, there are data quality issues with the files.  Some files have 13 columns, some have 14 columns, some use quotes for text fields that contain commas, some do not use quotes and produce "extra" columns, etc.  There are more problems that I have described, but I have been able to handle all of them with a script transformation in my data flow -- with the exception of the problem described in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching quotes and regular expression don't go hand in hand, and you are probably better of using a CSV parser, as Michael Madsen suggested.
However, if you know the quotes only occur as you expect, you can do something like the following:

```
str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "\"[^\"]*\"",
                     match => match.Value.Trim('\"').Replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last bit be `.Replace(",", "")`?

Comment: @Registered User - Thanks! That's a lambda expression by the way - an anonymous function, just like `delegate` from previous versions of C#. In a way it does look over matches, but in a subtle way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure regex version:

```
str2 = Regex.Replace(str0, 
          @"""|,(?=(?>[^""]*""[^""]*(?:""[^""]*""[^""]*)*)$)", 
          String.Empty);
```

It matches any quotation mark, or a comma if it's followed by an odd number of quotation marks, and replaces it with nothing.

I would only go this route if I absolutely had to, for example if I were working with a framework that only let me specify the regex and the replacement string.  Otherwise, I would either go with @Kobi's approach (because it's so much more readable) or use a dedicated CSV processor.  They're not hard to find.

Comment: I went with Kobi's approach because it doesn't have to solely be limited to regex.  I just assumed there had to be a way to do it with regex since it seemed like an appropriate tool for the problem.  I am definately going to disect your code, though, to see if I can understand it and learn something useful from it.